# Holding Python variables in SPSS when the Syntax is run from another Python script

Tags: python, spss

In SPSS any variables created using Python within the BEGIN and END PROGRAM command will be stored in memory for the rest of the syntax. However if the Syntax is called from another Python Command from a different syntax then the created Python Variable will only exist within the BEGIN  and END program in which it was created. For Example:

In the SPSS insert script where the program is called:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM. 
import spss
spss.Submit ('''
INSERT FILE = '~~FILELOCATION~~'
        SYNTAX=INTERACTIVE ERROR=CONTINUE CD=NO.
    ''')
END PROGRAM.
```

In the ~~FILE LOCATION~~ being called:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.  
firstvar = "34"
END PROGRAM.

BEGIN PROGRAM.
secondvar = "23"
print(firstvar + secondvar)
END PROGRAM.
```

If the latter script is run from the insert file command from the first program, the result is that the firstvar is not carried over into the second BEGIN PROGRAM.

Is there a way of storing this variable in the memory of the Python program that is begin used to insert the file, as any variables here will exist in the entire inserted syntax? If this is not possible what is the best way of carrying variables created in one Python script to another while within an insert file command.

I hope that makes sense, if you have any questions to clarify the problem please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first program is creating a local variable named firstvar.  You can make this persist into the second program by assigning it explicitly to its module.  This is a little more orderly than throwing the variable into globals.

import sys
sys.modules[__name__].firstvar = 34

and referring to it as
sys.modules[__name__].firstvar
in the second program.

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine for me (albeit with very minor changes).

Here's a printback from the output log:

```
insert file="c:\temp\pytest.sps". 
  44  0  * Encoding: windows-1252. 
  45  0  BEGIN PROGRAM. 
  46  0  firstvar = "34" 
  47  0  print firstvar 
34 
  47  0  END PROGRAM. 
  48  0   
  49  0  BEGIN PROGRAM. 
  50  0  secondvar  = "23" 
  51  0  print secondvar 
23 
  51  0  END PROGRAM. 
  52  0   
  53  0  * End of INSERT and INCLUDE nesting level 01. 
BEGIN PROGRAM. 
print firstvar 
print secondvar 
END PROGRAM. 
34 
23
```

### Update:

I can replicate the issue now also and suprised to notice that also. There is an easy solution however which is to define the python variables as `globals`.

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.  
global firstvar
firstvar = "34"
END PROGRAM.
```

Comment: Jignesh I am a little confused by your code, are you calling the insert command from within a Python script? This is a crucial point

Comment: Thanks, sorry hadn't taken ntice of that. Edited original answer nonetheless with a solution.

Comment: Thanks Jignesh, didn't think of using global variables as the program doesn't need them when run outside of the begin program!